# I can't get Recaptcha to appear inside Facebox

Tags: php, recaptcha, facebox

Can u help me to show the Recaptcha in Facebox? It doesn't load the image & I hate it.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

require_once('../recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "APIIII"; // you got this from the signup page

?>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inquiry').ajaxForm({
        target: '#error',
        success: function() {
        $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'clean'
    };
</script> 

<div class="top_area">Contact</div>


    <div id="search_area">

    </div>
<div style="overflow-y: hidden;">
<form name="inquiry" id="inquiry" action="ck.php" method="post">
<div id="error"></div>
<table align="center">

<tr>
    <td align="right">Name: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td align="right">Email: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" /></td>
</tr>



<tr>
    <td align="right">Company: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comp" id="comp" value="" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right"></td>
    <td>
        <?php

              echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
            ?>

    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td valign="top"></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send"  />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>`
```

Thank you guys,

Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: any link you got for the demo and debugging

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the recaptcha AJAX API http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#AJAX

Include the AJAX API script in your page (the containing page NOT the page recaptcha is getting) Then call the create method of the Recaptcha object to create a new captcha.